# How can I extract clear contours in video with openCV library

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Hi everyone iam having some problem extracting clear contours from video. At the moment the contours look like a big mess. The steps i am following are:

1. Take a video as input
2. Convert it to gray-scale
3. Threshold it to binary
4. Find contours with cvFindContours()
5. Loop through contours and draw them using cvDrawContours

The code is below :

```
IplImage *inFrame;
IplImage *outFrame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
CvScalar inPixel, outPixel;

//J.M ================================================//
CvMemStorage *mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0), *polymem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq *contours = NULL, *ptr = NULL, *poly = NULL, *convex_hull = NULL;
IplImage *cc_color = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(outFrame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
CvScalar externalColor = CV_RGB( 255, 252, 0 );
CvScalar holeColor = CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 );
CvFont font;
int contourNum = 0;
//=========================================================================//

frame_no = 0;
processingVideo = true;
this->GetDlgItem(IDC_STOP)->EnableWindow(true);

CString title = "Video Processing";
cvNamedWindow(title, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(pathOutVideo,CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'),video->getFPS(),cvSize(width,height),1);

// variables for counting time
clock_t begin, current;
long int secs, rem_secs, t1, t2;
begin = clock();

while(inFrame=cvQueryFrame(video->getCapture()))
{
    if(!processingVideo)
        break;

    // close opencv window?
    if(cvGetWindowHandle(title)==NULL)
        break;

    //==============================================================================================//

    /*Create gray-scale image*/
    IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(outFrame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCvtColor(inFrame, im_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    outFrame = im_gray;

    /*Convert gray-scale image to binary*/
    IplImage* img_bw = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im_gray), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
    cvThreshold(im_gray, img_bw, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    outFrame = img_bw;

    contourNum = cvFindContours(outFrame, mem, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    /* I have tried using convex_hull but with no success
    convex_hull = cvConvexHull2( contours, polymem, CV_CLOCKWISE, 2 ); 
    poly = cvApproxPoly(convex_hull, sizeof(CvContour), polymem, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0); 
    float size = fabs(cvContourArea( poly, CV_WHOLE_SEQ )); */

    for (ptr = contours; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->h_next) {
            cvDrawContours(cc_color, ptr, externalColor, holeColor, -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
    }

    outFrame = cc_color;
    //==============================================================================================//
```

I have also provided image instances of the various step results.

1. source video input   ( http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/sourcevideo.jpg/ )
2. gray-scale video     ( http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/grayscalei.jpg/ )
3. binary video         ( http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/684/binaryi.jpg/ )
4. final contour output ( http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/finaloutput.jpg/ )

If you need more info, just say so :)
I was wondering if anyone of you guys can give me some advice as how to proceed or what I am doing wrong. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Step: 3 Threshold it to binary`  needs some improvement. I think you want contours to be drawn around a semantically meaningful objects. In this case, since same gray level values are part of many objects - the resultant image is not an accurate measure of object boundary.

What you need to is perhaps try segmentation approaches - such as watershed algorithms or region growing algorithms. There are many implementation in OpenCV itself.